# How to implement p:A=>Boolean in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have below HOF which takes function as an argument

```
def findFirst[A](ss:Array[A], p:A=>Boolean):Int ={
@tailrec
def loop(n:Int):Int ={
  if(p(ss(n))) n
  else if (n+1>=ss.length) -1
  else loop(n+1)
}
loop(0)
```

}

I can call the above function with the below parameters but I am wondering is there any better way to implement p?

```
println(findFirst(Array(6, 1,2,3,4,5,6) ,(a:Int)=> a.equals(6)))
```

Comment: Use `List` + pattern matching instead of `Array`

Comment: Why would that be "better" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So only regarding the "nicer way to implement the `p`", and assuming your coding in Scala 2 (based on the coding style), I suggest you do this:

```scala
def findFirst[A](ss: Array[A])(p: A => Boolean): Int = ...

// And then when calling the function:
findFirst(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))(_ == 6)
```

That's because in Scala 2 type inference is done from the left-most parenthesis, so the `A` is inferred to be `Int` from the first arguments set, and you can pass the `p` function in a very concise manner. And also it makes more sense when you can use curried functions, doesn't it? You pass the array in the first argument set, and the function in the second one, it's like "find first elemnt in the array, that satisfies the p predicate"

Comment: @GPopat actually I don't see any "harcoding" here in your function **implementation** itself! What part do you mean?

Comment: please ignore my previous comment. I got your point now.